# [Mobile][Safari]Event of back browser button on safari mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, back-button

How to get an event of back browser on mobile safari with state on URL?

```
ex: domain.com#a -> domain.com#b
```

when I click to back browser `domain.com#b -> domain.com#a` 
but it's not triggering any event (**popstate, pageshow, pushstate,** even when I use **setInterval** to check the change of state on the URL)

Answer (score 0):

I think 'hashchange' is what you are looking for